# Remove sound when simulating click using perform click?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, click

I am trying to simulate click on RecyclerView item View using perform click . I need to remove the sound as I am simulating this . How can I remove sound of this specific click

```
StoryView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView.performClick();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
yourbutton.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Can we get some explanation? This answer is not very good without it.

Comment: ok is simple ...
xml:
<button>
your parameters
</ button>

Java:
mybuttom = (Buttom) findViewById (R.id.myButton);
// disable the sound when you programmatically call the click

myButtom.performClick ();
myButtom.setSoundEffectsEnabled (false);

Comment: @Alejandro Welcome to [SO]. Be sure to check [answer].